# No visible @interface for 'NSFileManager' declares the selector 'moveItemAtPath:toPath:'

Tags: objective-c, macos, oop, apple-documentation

I'm trying to use the moveItemAtPath method, but I am getting an error about using an interface.

```
> #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
> 
> int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
>     @autoreleasepool { 
>         NSFileManager *manage = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
>         NSString *a = @"folder1/file.txt";
>         NSString *b = @"folder2/file.txt";
>         NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", a];
>         NSString *newPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", b];
> 
>         [manage moveItemAtPath:path toPath:newPath];
>     }
>     return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv); }
```

I don't get how looking at the UIViewController , as explained in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696856 is supposed to help.

This resource does not show an example of what needs to be imported     https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_in_Objective-C#Moving.2FRenaming_a_File

Comment: `moveItemAtPath:toPath: doesn't exist. Use `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` or `moveItemAtURL:toURL:error:` instead.

Comment: Oh, are you saying the error is not optional?

Comment: It's not because you put `nil` in a parameter, that it can be omitted!

Comment: The error parameter must be supplied, but you can pass null value if you really don’t want to know why it failed (if it fails). https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1413529-moveitematpath

Comment: The parameter names are part of the method name. See 'Methods Can Take Parameters' in [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW5)